# How to convert date time from MST to EST?

Tags: android, datetime, timezone, simpledateformat

Here is my sample code return same date, I am trying to convert MST date & time to EST date & time, can anyone give me a suggestion.
It should support android os 4.4.4 to 11.

```
var input ="2021-03-05T14:14:27.99"

        val formatMST: DateFormat =  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                    formatMST.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST")

        val formatEST: DateFormat =  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                    formatEST.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")

        val dateFormat: DateFormat =  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)

        var date = dateFormat.parse(input.replace("T", " "))
            date = dateFormat.parse(formatMST.format(date!!))
Log.d("mst_", "input:$input   ::  " + formatEST.format(date!!))
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Does your code work? Why are you asking for a suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime                                             // Represent a date with time-of-day but lacking the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.
.parse( "2021-03-05T14:14:27.99" )                        // Parse text in standard ISO 8601 format.
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Denver" ) )                  // Place that date with time-of-day into the context of a time zone. Determines a moment. Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )   // Adjust into anther time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time. Returns another `ZonedDateTime` object, per immutable objects pattern.
.format(                                                  // Generate text representing the value without our `ZonedDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )              // Automatically localize.
    .withLocale( Locale.US )                              // Returns a `DateTimeFormatter` object. 
)                                                         // Returns a `String` object.
```

See this code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/TCViJX).

> Friday, March 5, 2021 at 4:14:27 PM Eastern Standard Time

## Details

Never use the terrible `java.util.Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. These legacy classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Parse your input string as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) because it lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. The text format complies with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```java
String input = "2021-03-05T14:14:27.99" ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

If you are certain that value was intended to represent a moment as seen in a particular time zone, apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Never use the 2-4 pseudo-zone codes such as `MST` and `EST`. These are not standardized. These are not even unique! Use [real time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the format of `Continent/Region` (with some exceptions like `America/Indiana/Indianapolis`, `Arctic/Longyearbyen` etc.).

```java
ZoneId zoneDenver = ZoneId.of( "America/Denver" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtDenver = ldt.atZone( zoneDenver ) ;
```

Adjust into another time zone. Same moment, the same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```java
ZoneId zoneNewYork = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = zdtDenver.withZoneSameInstant( zoneNewYork ) ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

### Fixing the published data feed

If your input string really was meant to represent a moment in a Mountain Time zone, then your data feed is broken. Vital data is missing.

I suggest you educate the publisher of that date about including that valuable information within the data.

One option is using the extension to the ISO 8601 format used by [`ZonedDateTime#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString()) where, in addition to the offset being present, the name of the time zone is appended in square brackets.

> 2021-03-05T14:14:27.990-07:00[America/Denver]

Or, the publisher of the data could adjust to UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) before generating the text. In [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, the `Z` on the end means an offset of zero and is pronounced “Zulu” per aviation/military tradition. Generally, this is the best approach. Programmers, testers, and admins should generally be thinking and working in UTC unless a business rule demands otherwise.

> 2021-03-05T21:14:27.990Z

Both options are [demonstrated live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/4DCKlO).

```java
System.out.println(
    LocalDateTime
    .parse( "2021-03-05T14:14:27.99" )
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Denver" ) )
    .toString()
);
```

… and …

```java
System.out.println(
    LocalDateTime
    .parse( "2021-03-05T14:14:27.99" )
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Denver" ) )
    .toInstant()
    .toString()
);
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            val instance = Calendar.getInstance()
            val timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Denver") // from MST or America/Denver
            // set time zone
            instance.timeZone = timeZone

            // set the input
            instance.set(Calendar.HOUR, 2) //hour
            instance.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 14) //minute
            instance.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2021) //year
            instance.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3) //month
            instance.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5) //day

            val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US)
            dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")
            Log.d("expire01", "output to convert date time from MST to EST : ${dateFormat.format(instance.time)}")
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            Log.d("expire01", "catch : ${e.message}")
        }
```

Result

```
// output to convert date time from MST to EST : 05 Apr 2021 04:14
```

this is one of the solution